# XPath compare child's value with parent's attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

This is the XML context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <travel  Selectedcity="USPDX" CitySeq="2">
    <travelcode>01</travelcode>
    <cities>
      <city>
        <seqno>3</seqno>
        <city_code>USPDX</city_code>
        <arrival>2015-04-23T14:37:00.143</arrival>
      </city>
      <city>
        <seqno>1</seqno>
        <city_code>JPHIC</city_code>
        <arrival>2015-05-09T06:26:00</arrival>
      </city>
      <city>
        <seqno>2</seqno>
        <additional_code>11222</additional_code>
        <city_code>USPDX</city_code>
        <arrival>2015-04-20T20:35:00</arrival>
      </city>
    </cities>
  </travel>
</root>
```

I'm looking for the arrival of the city indicated by the CitySeq attribute of travel (CitySeq="2"). So what I need to match is **seqno = CitySeq**. The result I expect is `<arrival>2015-04-20T20:35:00</arrival>`.

This is working: `/travel/cities/city[seqno=2]/arrival`

But replacing the "2" is not: `/travel/cities/city[seqno=/travel/@CitySeq]/arrival`

Suggestions? (thanks in advance)

Comment: BTW, I am using this site to test it: http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm. As example: XPATH(/travel/cities/city[seqno=3]/arrival)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I tested the following expression at http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

```
/root/travel/cities/city[seqno=/root/travel/@CitySeq]/arrival
```

I got a result:

```
Element='<arrival>2015-04-20T20:35:00</arrival>'
```

**OLD answer:** I don't think XPath supports such embedded expressions. Your best bet is to do this in two steps. Pseudo-code follows (assuming Java):

```
String citySeq = xPath.compile("/travel/@CitySeq").evaluate(xmlDocument);
String arrival = xPath.compile("/travel/cities/city[seqno="  + citySeq + "]/arrival").evaluate(xmlDocument);
```

Also, you should probably test against the possibility that the citySeq is not found in the first place.

Comment: If there could be multiple `travel` elements, it is not correct since the predicate is true if there exists a `travel` element that has a `CitySeq` attribute with the value of `seqno`. It is better to use `ancestor` as the other answer used it

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is using `ancestor` axis to get to the corresponding `travel` ancestor element.

```
/root/travel/cities/city[seqno=ancestor::travel/@CitySeq]/arrival
```

This will help especially in the case when there are multiple `travel` elements in the `root`.